# Insert statement takes too long on SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, triggers, insert

I am new to this. I have the following code which inside and SSID package takes too long to excecute.

This statement is meant to find the best lawyer (taking under consideration some productivity and capacity factors) and write its ID to a temporary table ...BUT IT TAKES TOO LONG.

Any Suggestions??? I even tried... disabling the trigers

```
ALTER TABLE TB_TEMPLawyer DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE TB_LAWYERS     DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE  TB_PCRelation  DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE  TB_CASES       DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE  TB_TEMPaccount  DISABLE TRIGGER ALL

INSERT INTO TB_TEMPLawyer
                      (LawyerAutoIDTEMP)
SELECT     TOP (1) TB_LAWYERS.LawyerAutoID
FROM         TB_PCRelation INNER JOIN
                      TB_CASES ON TB_PCRelation.PostalCode = TB_CASES.CustomerPostalCode INNER JOIN
                      TB_LAWYERS ON TB_PCRelation.PCLawyerID = TB_LAWYERS.LawyerID INNER JOIN
                      TB_TEMPaccount ON TB_CASES.Account = TB_TEMPaccount.TempAccount
WHERE     (TB_CASES.LASYstatus = '2') AND (TB_CASES.LawyerID = 'NONE') AND (TB_LAWYERS.Activity = 'ACTIVE') AND 
                      (TB_LAWYERS.Relation_Type = 'EXTERNAL') AND (TB_CASES.TotalMLUSBBexposure BETWEEN TB_LAWYERS.MINAmount AND 
                      TB_LAWYERS.MAXamount) AND (TB_LAWYERS.CaseLimitMONTHLY >= TB_LAWYERS.CaseLimitMONTHLYactual) AND 
                      (TB_LAWYERS.CaseLimitDAILY >= TB_LAWYERS.CaseLimitDAILYactual) AND (TB_LAWYERS.Productivity <> '0')
ORDER BY TB_LAWYERS.Productivity DESC




ALTER TABLE TB_TEMPLawyer ENABLE TRIGGER ALL 
ALTER TABLE TB_LAWYERS     ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE  TB_PCRelation  ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE  TB_CASES       ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
ALTER TABLE  TB_TEMPaccount  ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

Comment: Try to see the estimated query plan to find the bottleneck

Comment: Try running the same query in SSMS and see how it's performing. Get the execution plan as well for this query.

Comment: Although yesterday the performance was dramatically improved , today again i faced the same problem. The Database Engine Tunning Advisor give me no new HINTS and SUGGESTIONS. Any ideas????

Answer (score 0):

First, triggers would have nothing to do with the performance.  You are only inserting one row.

There are two problems you could face in an insert of this sort:

1. The destination table could be locked for some reason.  I doubt this is the problem.
2. The query is taking a long time.

Run the query in SSMS.

Judging from the naming conventions, I would be suspicious of this join:

```
FROM TB_PCRelation INNER JOIN 
     TB_CASES
     ON TB_PCRelation.PostalCode = TB_CASES.CustomerPostalCode
```

There is not an obvious restriction on the cases.  You very well might have a lot of lawyers and a lot of cases in a single postal code.

However, this is just speculation.